# Match only certain part instead of whole line

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have bunch of text like this:

```
some text <a href="../media/image/aaa.html">aaa</a> some text
some text <a href="aaa.html">aaa</a> some text
some text <a href="bbb.html">aaa</a> some text
some text <a href="../media/ccc.html">aaa</a> some text
```

how do I search and match only the part :

```
href="
```

for those link that dont have

```
href="../media/
```

example will match only:

```
some text <a href="aaa.html">aaa</a> some text
some text <a href="bbb.html">aaa</a> some text
```

instead of match whole line, it will matchthe **href="** part
so that i can replace it with notepad++ or powergrep

i tried:

```
^(?!.*..\/).*href=".*$
```

it do not working:

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aK6sB5/41)

[this one work](https://regex101.com/r/aK6sB5/42), but, it match the whole line

any help would be great.

Comment: Note that regex has no capability of highlighting anything. That's entirely a UI thing, which has nothing to do with regex.

Comment: href=(?!"?\.), this one work match as your expect, but do not know how to highlighting ...

Comment: instead of highlight should i change the word to `match`

Comment: @yudongshen : thanks, yes that is working and what i needed. https://regex101.com/r/aK6sB5/43 how to make to match the third row as well, as currently it only match the 2nd row.

Comment: @Teddybugs, you need flag g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not far with your second regex (`^(?!.*..\/media\/).*href=".*$`) but you are selecting the whole line (hence the highlighting in the UI) because of `.*` and `.*$`. Furthermore, the zero-width negative look ahead needs to be put **after** the pattern you are looking for. Altogether [you want](https://regex101.com/r/aK6sB5/44):

`href="(?!\.\.\/media)`

Note the `g` switch to make sure all occurrences are matched, not only the first one.